# TeamCity TestComplete runner in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to using Python and the following is the first script that I have written. I will execute a test complete project and will be started via team city. Once test execute has been called - the log file needs to be processed for consumption through TeamCity.

```
import sys
import argparse
import subprocess
import os.path

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--projectSuite", help=".pjs that you want to execute", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--project", help=".pj that you want to execute", type=str, default="ExploratoryTests")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--logDirectory", help="The directory to log the mht's too", type=str, default="C:\TestLogs")
parser.add_argument("-lf", "--logFile", help="The name of the log", type=str, default="TextExecuteLog.mht")
parser.add_argument("-ps", "--psexec", help="Absolute path to psexec", type=str, default="c:\Program Files (x86)\PsTools\PsExec.exe")
parser.add_argument("-te", "--testExecute", help="Absolute path to testExecute", type=str, default="c:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 9\Bin\TestExecute.exe")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mhtExtractor", help="Absolute path to an mht extractor", type=str, default="C:\extract2htm\extractMHT.exe")

#Get the args that are passed in
args = parser.parse_args()

#Make sure we have an absolute path
suite = os.path.abspath(args.projectSuite)

#Prepare the project for consumption by TestExecute
project = "/p:" + args.project

#Get a path for the currenct mht
logFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(args.logDirectory, args.logFile))

#Tell TestExecute where to put the log
log = "/exportlog:" + logFile

#prepare TE Executables
psexec = os.path.abspath(args.psexec);
testExecute = os.path.abspath(args.testExecute)

#Execute testExecute through psexec
testExecuteCommand = [psexec,"-i" ,"-accepteula", testExecute, suite, project, "/exit", log, "/r", "/DoNotShowLog", "/SilentMode"]

#Blank array to hold the TE outcome
testExecuteError = [];

try:
    result = subprocess.run(args = testExecuteCommand, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    result.check_returncode()
    testExecuteError.append(result)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    result = e.returncode
    testExecuteError.append(e)
    print("Error code: {0}".format(result))

extractor = os.path.abspath(args.mhtExtractor)
outputDir = os.path.join(args.logDirectory)

extractorExecuteCommand = [extractor, logFile, outputDir]

try:
    result = subprocess.run(args = extractorExecuteCommand, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    result.check_returncode()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    result = err.returncode
    print("Error code: {0}".format(result))


#exit the script with the exit code from testexetute
sys.exit(testExecuteError[0])
```

The way in which I handle my exceptions from testExecute are the part that I'm not happy about but it is working as intended. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type=str` is already the default way `argparse` interprets things. However, for all the options where the only further processing is calling `os.path.abspath`, you can use that as type. This affects `args.psexec` and `args.testExecute`.

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which you should follow. It recommends using `lower_case_with_underscore` for variables and functions.

[Comments should explain *why* the code is the way it is, not *what* it does](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The latter should be obvious from the code itself, the name of the function you encapsulated it in and/or the [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) accompanying that function.

In that vein, you could use more functions. One candidate for this would be `get_args`, where you can stick all your `argparse` code. Also the two `subprocess` calls could be in their own function, since they are completely independent. The least you should do is wrap your code in `if __name__ == "__main__":`. This way you can import this module from another script without running the tests.

In Python, `;` serve (almost) no purpose, even though they are not a `SyntaxError`. You definitely do not need them at the end of normal lines.

**Final code**:

```
import sys
import argparse
import subprocess
import os.path

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--projectSuite", help=".pjs that you want to execute", type=os.path.abspath)
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--project", help=".pj that you want to execute", default="ExploratoryTests")
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--logDirectory", help="The directory to log the mht's too", default="C:\TestLogs", type=os.path.join)
    parser.add_argument("-lf", "--logFile", help="The name of the log", default="TextExecuteLog.mht")
    parser.add_argument("-ps", "--psexec", help="Absolute path to psexec", type=os.path.abspath, default="c:\Program Files (x86)\PsTools\PsExec.exe")
    parser.add_argument("-te", "--testExecute", help="Absolute path to testExecute", type=os.path.abspath, default=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 9\Bin\TestExecute.exe")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--mhtExtractor", help="Absolute path to an mht extractor", type=os.path.abspath, default="C:\extract2htm\extractMHT.exe")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.project = "/p:" + args.project
    args.logFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(args.logDirectory, args.logFile))
    args.log = "/exportlog:" + logFile
    return args


def execute_test(psexec, testExecute, suite, project, log, **kwargs):
    """Execute testExecute through psexec"""
    command = [psexec,"-i" ,"-accepteula", testExecute, suite, project, "/exit", log, "/r", "/DoNotShowLog", "/SilentMode"]

    #Blank array to hold the TE outcome
    testExecuteError = []
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(args=command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        result.check_returncode()
        testExecuteError.append(result)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        testExecuteError.append(e)
        print("Error code: {0.returncode}".format(e))
    return testExecuteError


def execute_extractor(mhtExtractor, logDirectory, logFile, **kwargs):
    """Descriptive docstring"""
    command = [extractor, logFile, logDirectory]
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(args=command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        result.check_returncode()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error code: {.returncode}".format(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = vars(get_args())
    testExecuteError = execute_test(**args)
    execute_extractor(**args)

    sys.exit(testExecuteError[0])
```

Note that I made all parameters part of the `argparse.Namespace` to have it all in one place. Afterwards I used `vars` to convert it to a `dict`. Then I used keyword arguments to make the function calls easier but at the same time giving the parameters of the function names.

To see how the dictionary unpacking works, have a look at this example:

```
def f(x, y, **kwargs):
    print x, y, kwargs

def g(x, z, **kwargs):
    print x, z, kwargs

args = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
f(**args)
# 1 2 {'z': 3}
f(1, 2)
# 1 2 {}
g(**args)
# 1 3 {'y': 2}
```

`kwargs` swallows all left-over keyword arguments and allows in my code above the passing in of the whole `args` dict, even though both functions need only some of its content.

Comment: Thank you kindly for showing me some tricks here - i have taken your comments on board and I will improve my script further.